# activerecord sql difficult query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I need to make a query with two options: first - select DISTINCT ON, secondly - order by (and order by other fields). BTW, having by don't work

At one sql forum I find a solution

```
WITH d AS (
SELECT DISTINCT ON ({Dlist}) {slist}
FROM {flist}
....
)
SELECT * FROM d ORDER BY {order fields}
```

So, how I can make this via ActiveRecord method and get back ActiveRecord::Relation

My full query seems something like that:

```
WITH d AS (
SELECT DISTINCT ON(item_info_id, volume) items.item_info_id, items.volume, items.* 
FROM "items" INNER JOIN "item_info" ON "item_info"."id" = "items"."item_info_id" WHERE "items"."type" IN ('Product') 
AND "items"."published" = 't' 
AND ("items"."item_info_id" IS NOT NULL) 
AND ("items"."price" BETWEEN 2 AND 823489)\
)
SELECT * FROM d ORDER_BY 'price'
```

Comment: Can you show us one working mysql query example, I mean complete query

Comment: Sure. See full postgresql query. I need something like this in activerecord, which will return ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: btw, would you like to describe the output of this query, as if you are telling it to your product manager. You know what one needs to spend some little amount of time to understand what this is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below might work for you or give you some hints

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.what_you_want_to_achieve
    item_ids = where("item_info_id IS NOT NULL")
              .select(" DISTINCT on(item_info_id, volume) items.item_info_id, items.volume, items.id ")
              .map(&:id)

    where(:id => item_ids).published.products.price_between(2,823489).order(:price)
  end
```

I assume you know how to define `scope` e.g. `published`

Comment: I think it will be work. Many thanks, guy. Please wait, I'll try it out